# XP box with 3 NICs on Server 2003 Domain

Tags: networking, windows-xp, nic, port-mirroring

I have assigned all three NICs IP addresses that are outside the DHCP pool. I have 2 NICs are connected to  1 switch and the 3rd to my second switch.

I want to assign one of the two NICs on the 1st switch to "normal" network activity (e.g. internet access, RDP, etc.)

The other two NICs I want to reserve for mirroring ports on their respective switches.

While this machine is connected to the domain I can access the internet and Remote Desktop. I have no idea which NIC I am using until I start mirroring a port, at which time, if I happen to be connected through one of the NICs I have dedicated to mirroring, I lose my remote desktop.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of control would you have with Linux that you don't have with Windows?

Here's one way to do this:

Unbind TCP/IP from the NIC's you're using for port mirroring. TCP/IP doesn't need to be bound to the NIC for port mirroring to work.

Comment: Your exhortation that you would have more control with Linux than with Windows is more likely to incite a Linux vs. Windows troll match than to avoid it. Keep us posted on your progress.

Comment: That's strange. I run captures with Wireshark and several other packet capture programs with TCP/IP unbound to the NIC I'm capturing on without any issues.

Comment: Hopefully that helps you accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Default Gateway from both NICs that you don't want to access the internet on.